# python : how to handle NaN data on if statement

Tags: python

I've got a csv file where some of data is empty. When I use an `if` statement, the `NaN` data is included to `else` statement.

```
def warna_kota(population):
    if population < 10000:
        return 'green'
    elif 10000 <= population < 20000:
        return 'orange'
    elif 20000 <= population < 30000:
        return 'brown'
    elif 40000 <= population < 50000:
        return 'yellow' 
    elif 60000 <= population < 70000:
        return 'blue'
    elif 80000 <= population < 90000:
        return 'gold'
    elif 90000 <= population < 100000:
        return 'pink'
    else:
        return 'red'
```

The result shows that `NaN` data is red, I tried to use this,

```
if population = NaN:
    return 'grey'
elif:
    ...
```

However, when I try to run the code, it produces an error.
The `NaN` data is empty, and I want to separate `NaN` data from the `else` statement. How would I do that?

Comment: You can use `if population!=population:` to check if your variable is NaN

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds `population == np.nan` wouldn't work because `==` doesn't work for nan.

Comment: Use the suggested answer or use `try: except:` to test whether the value is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `math.isnan(population)` for that check.

```
import math

# ...

if math.isnan(population):
    return 'grey'
```